# How to Select a value in <select> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is the Select tag That I used..

```
<select class="form-control" id="VillagesComboidmod">
  <option>Kandy</option>
  <option>Ampitiya</option>
  <option>Semaneriya</option>
</select>
```

This is the code that I used to select a value..

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboid').value = "Ampitiya";
```

Comment: use `==` `document.getElementById('VillagesComboid').value == "Ampitiya";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your select like below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="VillagesComboidmod">
  <option value="Kandy">Kandy</option>
  <option value="Ampitiya">Ampitiya</option>
  <option value="Semaneriya">Semaneriya</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Answer (score 2):

You've just got a typo in the reference to the element id.

To set the value of the `<select>` element

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboid').value = "Ampitiya";
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboidmod').value = "Ampitiya";
```

Here it is working on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nibehiv/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you.. :-) I just got it

Comment: Glad to hear it @SupunSasiduMadushankaSupun0 Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use, **`==`, for comparision**. and **`=` for assignment**

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboid').value == "Ampitiya";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select class="form-control" id="VillagesComboidmod">
  <option>Kandy</option>
  <option>Ampitiya</option>
  <option>Semaneriya</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById("VillagesComboidmod").value == "Ampitiya");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above CODE**

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aixqEI9i2eQnguGmgaRZ?p=preview)

Comment: @Supun Sasidu Madushanka Supun0, please check my answer and the example. you no need to add the `value` to options tag. just select a value and click on try it.

Answer (score 0):

just change your id

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboid').value='Ampitiya';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('VillagesComboidmod').value='Ampitiya';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<select class="form-control" id="VillagesComboidmod">
 <option value="K">Kandy</option>
 <option value="A">Ampitiya</option>
 <option value="S">Semaneriya</option>
</select>


<script>
  document.getElementById('VillagesComboidmod').value = 'A';
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```